# QMainWindow not catching signal from QThread

Tags: multithreading, qt, c++11, thread-safety, qt4

> When I emit signal to MainWindow from QObject which is running in different thread why MainThread doesn't catch it, I am using Ubuntu 16.04
>    sometime it catch but that only happen once after that the thread continues to run in event loop,
>    i just want to finish the thread if some work is done and after then i have to reuse it....

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    class newiDeviceDetect *deviceDetect;

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;


public slots:
    void on_deviceDetected();

};


class newiDeviceDetect : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit newiDeviceDetect(QObject *parent = 0);
    QThread *newDeviceThread;

signals:
    void killMe();

public slots:
    void threadWorker();
};


MainWindow *mainClass;
static void usbHotPlugDetectHand(int sig)
{
    qDebug() << "GOT SIGNAL" + QString::number(sig);
    emit mainClass->usbHotPlugDetect();
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mainClass = this;

    deviceDetect = new newiDeviceDetect;
    connect(deviceDetect,SIGNAL(killMe()),this,SLOT(on_deviceDetected()));

    signal(SIGUSR1,usbHotPlugDetectHand);
    connect(this,SIGNAL(usbHotPlugDetect()),this,SLOT(on_usbHotPlugDetect()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_usbHotPlugDetect()
{
    deviceDetect->threadLock.lock();
    deviceDetect->newDeviceThread->start();
}

void MainWindow::on_deviceDetected()
{
    deviceDetect->newDeviceThread->terminate();
    deviceDetect->newDeviceThread->wait();
    deviceDetect->threadLock.unlock();
}

newiDeviceDetect::newiDeviceDetect(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    newDeviceThread = new QThread;
    connect(newDeviceThread,SIGNAL(started()),this,SLOT(threadWorker()));
    moveToThread(newDeviceThread);
    //Some Work
}

void newiDeviceDetect::threadWorker()
{
    sleep(5);
    //Some Work

    killMe();
}
```

> in my code threadWorker is working fine but when it signal killMe to MainWindow, MainWindow Class doest catch it,, i have to finish/terminate newDeviceThread to use it again
>
> Any Help Appreciated, Thankyou

Comment: On which operating system? How are the `QThread` running? Do each of them has its event loop?

Comment: on Linux, I dont have much knowledge whats going on under the hood @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: Please improve your question by editing it, don't comment it.

Comment: As Basile said, your question doesn't make it clear how you've started the thread. Presumably you have a call to newDeviceThread->start(); in the //Some work section. I suspect that it isn't going to work because your worker thread doesn't have an event loop. A quick google for "qt signals without event loop" comes up with an answer that says you need an event loop...

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the signal for every new thread you create, it seems you only do it once and your code looks a little chaotic to me.

I mean after

```
newDeviceThread = new QThread;
connect(newDeviceThread,SIGNAL(started()),this,SLOT(threadWorker()));
```

you also need a connect to the slot that terminates your worker thread, in your case I think `MainWindow::on_deviceDetected()`?

Also what exactly is this supposed to do? `class` creates a new class and maybe that's not what you want in that case...

```
class newiDeviceDetect *deviceDetect;
```